# Safely allowing user provided content in PHP file

Tags: php, validation

Consider the following script:

```
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/myfile.php', $header.$_POST['users_html'].$footer);
```

`$header` and `$footer` are safe, however, `$_POST['users_html']` is suspect.

The intent is `$_POST['users_html']` is HTML, but obviously someone could maliciously post something else. The content will not be stored in a DB or used in a SMS, and `/var/www/html/myfile.php` will be public and only opened by Apache.  While I didn't show it and am not asking about this part, after I know `$_POST['users_html']` is safe, I will be replacing certain tags such as `{{1}}` to `<?php echo(getSomething(1));?>` using regex.

Assume I am not concerned with JavaScript threats, and my only concern is someone running PHP on the server which I did not intend.

Other than ensuring that `$_POST['users_html']` doesn't contain any `<?` tags, what should be done?

Comment: It all depends on what you are going to do / others can do with the file once you have created it.

Comment: @PeeHaa  They could execute  it http://example.com/myfile.php.  What else do you mean?  Thanks

Comment: htmlentities  and mysqli_real_escape_string will help you

Comment: @user1844933  Not concerned about JavaScript.  Also, don't know what sql has to do with it.  Thanks

Comment: Will it be displayed as HTML? As text? As CSV? XML? Will the data be used in the database at some point? Are you putting the data in an SMS? Are you going to open the file in a certain application? Will the file be public? In order to know whether something needs to be done you need to know what you are trying to prevent / protect against.

Comment: @PeeHaa  The intent is it is HTML, but obviously someone could maliciously post something else.  It will not be stored in a DB.  The file will be public and only opened by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only going to be pure HTML, then treat it as such. DO NOT put in into a PHP file - it will end up being run like a little Bobby PHP script.  Save to a separate file (outside the web-root, so it cannot be accessed directly from the website).

Never include/require it, always `echo file_get_contents()` or `fpassthru()` the file and BEFORE you save it, run the code through a Whitelist HTML filter - such as the [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library, and then put it to disk or database.

So, probably not a great idea, but at least this way, you'll have a chance.

Comment: As described, I will be replacing certain tags such as `{{1}}` to `<?php echo(getSomething(1));?>` using regex, so ultimately it will need to be executed as PHP.  The script will be executed often, but only parsed rarely.  I "could" parse it every time and treat it as HTML, however, this will not be efficient.  I understand that twig/smarty do something similar.

Comment: Upon going through the twig source code, I stand corrected, and it doesn't quite do so.  My question, however, still remains.